# Laravel Livewire: load livewire component with button click

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, livewires

There are 3 livewire components `UserIsExpired`, `UserIsActive` and `UserIsPending` and 3 buttons respective to each component. When a button is clicked, it should replace previous component with its respective component.

```
<button wire:click="$emit(active)">{{ __('Active') }}</button>
<button wire:click="$emit(pending)">{{ __('Pending') }}</button>
<button wire:click="$emit(expired)">{{ __('Expired') }}</button>
```

In view

```
<livewire:user-is-active :active="$active"/>
<livewire:user-is-pending :pending="$pending"/>
<livewire:user-is-expired :expired="$expired"/>
```

Component example

```
class UserIsExpired extends Component
{
    protected $listeners = ['expired'];    
    public function render()
    {
        return <<<'blade'
            <div>
                {{-- The best athlete wants his opponent at his best. --}}
            </div>
        blade;
    }
}
```

When `Active` button is clicked, it should load `UserIsActive` component. Same goes for other two.

I have been looking livewire doc for long, but unable to find how to make it happen. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8):

I would wrap your `components` in a `component container` and use it to manage the visibility of your other `components`.

**component-contaoner.blade.php**

```html
<div>
    <h4>Component Container</h4>

    {{-- this is your dynamic component --}}
    @livewire($component, key($key))

    <button wire:click="$emit('switch', 'active')">
        {{ __('Active') }}
    </button>

    <button wire:click="$emit('switch', 'pending')">
        {{ __('Pending') }}
    </button>

    <button wire:click="$emit('switch', 'expired')">
        {{ __('Expired') }}
    </button>
</div>
```

**ComponentContainer.php**

```php
class ComponentContainer extends Component
{
    private $component = '';

    protected $listeners = [
        'switch'
    ];

    public function switch(string $component)
    {
        $this->component = $component;
    }

    public function mount(string $component = 'active')
    {
        $this->component = $component;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.component-container', [
            'component' => $this->component,
            // key is required to force a refresh of the container component
            'key' => random_int(-999, 999),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Then you would use the `component container` as follows, passing in an optional `component` to show initially otherwise it defaults to `active` as set in the `mount` function.

```html
@livewire('component-container')
```

You could put the `buttons` anywhere you want and use

```
$emitTo('container-component', 'switch', 'active')
```

I just put them inside the `component-container` for ease.

A nice thing about this approach is there are no `if` conditionals to manage and should you add more `components` to switch between, all you need to do is add another `button` somewhere with the relevant `$emit`.

Comment: Just came across this and it will be incredibly useful for something I'm trying to do. One minor nitpick: the random range for the key seems small to consistently guarantee a refresh. I assume it's just an illustrative number choice, but maybe something like random_int(PHP_INT_MIN, PHP_INT_MAX) will reduce issues for people that copy/paste without thinking about it. Maybe even using time (microseconds since epoch) could be more reliable than a random number.

Comment: @anjama The values were purely illustrational, feel free to adapt and use whatever mechanism is appropriate for your use case. Glad it could be of use to you though.

Comment: You can do without passing 'component' in the view if you set the `$component` property to `public`'.

Comment: This method somehow seems to trigger the "Multiple root elements detected." error in the console even though each component only has one element. Do you have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: @Joseph Difficult to say without seeing your code. Perhaps [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)?

Comment: @Peppermintology I was referring to the code provided in this answer. Sorry if that wasn't clear. I did ask a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75112448) but didn't get any responses. However, I've since figured out the issue and answered my own question there.

Comment: That's clever :) It can also be triggered by javascript too.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is be adding all listeners to **each** of the components and switch a flag. Here on the example of `UserIsExpired`:

```php
class UserIsExpired extends Component
{
    public $state = 'invisible';

    protected $listeners = [
        'active',
        'pending',
        'expired',
    ];

    public function active()
    {
        $this->state = 'invisible';
    }

    public function pending()
    {
        $this->state = 'invisible';
    }

    public function expired()
    {
        $this->state = 'visible';
    }

    public function render()
    {
        if ($this->state === 'invisble') {
            return '';
        }

        return <<<'blade'
            <div>
                {{-- The best athlete wants his opponent at his best. --}}
            </div>
        blade;
    }
}
```

For the initially visible component you probably want to set the default value for the `state` to visible.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can take is setting a self property and in blade make the corresponding livewire directive like if/else (assuming all is under full page component and the model binding refer a user model)

```
<button wire:click="showNested('active')">{{ __('Active') }}</button>
<button wire:click="showNested('pending')">{{ __('Pending') }}</button>
<button wire:click="showNested('expired')">{{ __('Expired') }}</button>
```

In view

```
@if($show == 'isActive')
   <livewire:user-is-active :active="$active"/>
@elseif($show == 'isPending')
   <livewire:user-is-pending :pending="$pending"/>
@elseif($show == 'isExpired')
   <livewire:user-is-expired :expired="$expired"/>
@endif
```

in component

```
public $active,$pending,$expired;
public $show = '';

public function render()
{
   if(!empty($this->show)){
      if($this->show == 'active')
         $this->active = User::where('status','active')->first();
      elseif(....)
        //......
   }
   return view(.....) //......;  
}

public function showNested($value)
{
   $this->show = $value;
}
```